# Show DIV corresponding to datepicker selection

Tags: jquery, html, user-interface, datepicker

Using the latest version of jquery ui's datepicker, I want to show one hidden div depending on the date selected.

The idea is to have datepicker displayed inline, and when the user selects a date, a hidden div corresponding with that date will show.

Here's what I've got so far... I think I need to use onSelect but I'm having trouble putting it together based on other stackoverflow questions.

```
    $("#inlinedatepicker").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(date) {
        $('.tohide').hide();
        $('#date' + date).show();
    },
    inline: true,
    minDate: new Date(currentYear),
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        if (date.getDay() == 0 || date.getDay() == 1 || date.getDay() == 2 || date.getDay() == 3) {
            return [false, ''];
        } else {
            return [true, ''];
        }
    }
});
```

So if you selected January 1, 2013, the div with ID= date01/01/2013 would display.  I assume the slashes aren't accepted, so is there a way to work around this?

The HTML for the Jan 1 2013 div would look like this...

```
<div id="date01/01/2013">...</div>
```

Comment: Can you update the error that you are getting with this code?

Comment: I don't receive an error.  The datepicker shows properly, but the date selected will not open the corresponding div.  I don't know if I'm properly capturing the date for the .show(); statement.

Comment: I am a little confused, so what is in this hidden div. Can you provide html?

Comment: try adding `alert('#date' + date)` in the onSelect function and check if it is same as the div ID.

Comment: Thanks Wolf, your alert suggestion along with some other feedback helped me modify the string so that the selector works well.  :]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the issues could be that the "date" that is passed into the onSelect eventhandler is a string in the format "01/18/2013" (depending on the Culture setting of the browser). And it looks like you are using this string (appended with date) to select the div. But the jQuery selectors will throw an exception when it encounters special characters like "/". One work around is to use

```
document.getElementById('date' + date).style.display = "block"; // this works  
                                                                // with "date01/18/2013"
```

You could also set the selector id without the slashes, and then in the onSelect event handler remove the slashes from the string, and use that in the jquery selector.

Comment: You seem to understand the issue and I also thought it might have something to do with the fact that the date is formatted with slashes, but I'm unsure of how to use the line of code you provided.

Comment: You can use the line of code I provided, instead of the line `$('#date' + date).show();`. However, to keep the DOM element selector code consistent, I think it is better to go with Option 2, which is to name the divs without the slashes, and in the event handler remove the slashes from the passed in "date" parameter, before using jQuery to show the div. _Please mark my solution as the answer if it helped solve your issue._